# D3 updating local data and redrawing pie as it is updated

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Building a D3 pie chart that should show player and score as percent of total scored. Data is built out on clicks and updates an array called `playersObj` that looks like...

```
var playersObj = [
    {"playerName":"Jessica Jones","playerID":157,"playerScore":2},
    {"playerName":"Luke Cage","playerID":158,"playerScore":0},
    {"playerName":"Matt Murdock","playerID":159,"playerScore":6}
]
```

Throughout my script I increment the playerScore and am attempting to update the chart accordingly. Here's the code I have so far where I set up the specifics and then attempt to draw it as data is updated...

```
/*
----------------------------------------------------------------------
DONUT CHART
----------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

//Set color range
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "orange"]);

//Set stage dimensions
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

//Select div and add svg into it
var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")

//Set inner and outer radius of chart
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(radius - 75);


//UPDATE THE DONUT

function updateDonut(){
    console.log("Updating donut...");
    //console.log(donutData);

    //Create pie chart
    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.playersScore;
      });

    var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
      .data(pie(playersObj))
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "arc");

    console.log(pie(playersObj));

    arcs.append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        //console.log(d);
        return color(d.data.playerName);
      });

    arcs.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
      })
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.firstName+": "+d.data.playersScore
      });

}
```

As a results of this, I get a chart with two problems. First, the chart appends text to entries that have a playerScore of 0. Seeing as how everybody starts with 0 a large number of names get stacked on top of each other since their slices of the pie has no value. Second problem is that the pie never updates after the second update. playersObj updates and `console.log(pie(playersObj));` shows the correct values but the chart display never changes.

I've seen the Bostock examples with the apples but that's changing out data and I simply need to update and redraw. Other posts seem to be taking different approaches so it's confusing to me how their solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

So, the biggest issue was misspelled variable names.  I've fixed most of the issues I found though some are opinionated.  I hope this helps.

```js
var playersObj = [{
  "playerName": "Jessica Jones",
  "playerID": 157,
  "playerScore": 3
}, {
  "playerName": "Luke Cage",
  "playerID": 158,
  "playerScore": 2
}, {
  "playerName": "Matt Murdock",
  "playerID": 159,
  "playerScore": 6
}, {
  "playerName": "Oliver Queen",
  "playerID": 160,
  "playerScore": 10
}, {
  "playerName": "Barry Allen",
  "playerID": 161,
  "playerScore": 3
}];

var domain = playersObj.map(function(m) {
  return m.playerID;
});

//Set color range
var color = d3.scale.category10();
// var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
//    .range(["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "orange"]);

//Set stage dimensions
var width = 300;
var height = 300;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

//Select div and add svg into it
var svg = d3.select("#donut").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var group = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")")

//Set inner and outer radius of chart
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(radius - 75);

function updateDonut() {
  console.log("Updating donut...");
  //console.log(donutData);

  //Create pie chart
  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) {
      return d.playerScore;
    });

  var enter = group.selectAll(".arc")
    .data(pie(playersObj))
    .enter();
  var arcs = enter.append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc");
  var text = enter.append("g")
    .attr("class", "text");

  console.log(pie(playersObj));

  arcs.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
      return color(d.data.playerID);
    });

  text.append("text")
    .attr("style", "text-anchor:middle")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.data.playerName + ": " + d.data.playerScore
    });

}

updateDonut();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #404040;
}
li,
text {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: white;
  fill: white;
}
#donut {
  padding: 2rem;
}
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Your `playersObj` shows `playerScore` (singular) while you text elements value assignment references `playersScore` (plural).
  </li>
  <li>You also referenced `firstName` in the text element, which doesn't exist in `playersObj`.
  </li>
  <li>
    `Luke Cage` could not be seen because his `playerScore` was 0.
  </li>
  <li>
    Add some padding to the svg container and let the overflow be visible. Lots of different ways to handle that...
  </li>
  <li>
    Color scheme was a bit difficult to read too and the text elements should/could be centered.
  </li>
  <li>
    After fixing the above, text was hidden behind each arc because the text was attached to the same g object as the arc. Attachment order makes the text below the next arc added to the pie. Attaching to separate g 'layers' from the enter selection solves
    this.
  </li>
</ul>
<div id='donut'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Will, I added a fiddle with your code to better illustrate what's happening and what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically, pie starts at 0, as player's scores increment, pie chart updates. Fiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/e2wyd1fr/

Comment: Managed to hide the cluster of overlapping labels with a simple if statement. Still can't update the pie. 

https://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/e2wyd1fr/1/